# Does the delegate::Invoke and ThreadPool::QueueWorkerItem in C# do the same job?

Tags: delegates, backgroundworker, begininvoke

The synchronous calls in C# can be converted to a asynchronous calls by creating a new delegate, and then the **BeginInvoke** can be called on that delegate. The same operation can be done by without creating a delegate, but call the **ThreadPool::QueueWorkerItem** method. As I understand both methods do the same job. The **delegate::BeginInvoke** is little more coding but easy to understand. Do these operations both use thread pool to do the asynchronous operation internally?

Answer (score 0):

After testing a sample app, I have found out that delegate::BeginInvoke invokes the call in a different thread. Internally it might be using ThreadPool to create a background worker thread to complete the job because the callback can't modify the controls which is created by the UI thread.